# how to save a php object to hashtable in php-extension?

Tags: php, php-extension

How to save a php object to hashtable and how to get a saved php obejct from hashtable in php-extension?

Here is my code:

```
//object_map has been init and alloc memory
//return_value is the return var of PHP_FUNCTION

zend_class_entry **class_ce,
object_init_ex(return_value, *class_ce); //create object
ioc_add_object_to_hash(name, return_value ); //save object

//find in the hashtable
if( zend_hash_find( object_map, name, sizeof(name), (void*)&return_value ) == SUCCESS ){

    php_printf("return_value:%p, %p,type:%d\n", return_value,&return_value, Z_TYPE_P(return_value));
    return 0;
}

//definition of ioc_add_object_to_hash
int ioc_add_object_to_hash( const char *name, zval *obj )
{
    if( !obj ){
        return -1;
    }
    if( !object_map ){
        return -1;
    }
    if( zend_hash_update( object_map, name, sizeof(name), obj, sizeof(*obj), NULL) == SUCCESS ){
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

PHP code:

```
   $filelist = array(
       "Foo" => realpath(__DIR__)."/Foo.php",
       "Bar" => realpath(__DIR__)."/Bar.php",
   );

   ioc::init( $filelist );


  var_dump(get_included_files());

  Bar::halo();

  $foo = ioc::make("Foo");

  echo $foo->get();

  $foo2 = ioc::make("Foo"); var_dump($foo2);
```

the $foo2 is NULL after second call ioc::make("Foo");

all my code is push to https://github.com/longmon/php-ioc.git.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hei,I solved myself! My purpose is get the object from hashtable, the problem is i did wrong way to init return_value, so i got the NULL.The right way would be like below:

```
if( !object_map ){
    php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_NOTICE, "object_map had not been alloced");
    return -1;
}
zval **obj;
if( zend_hash_find( object_map, name, sizeof(name), (void **)&obj ) == SUCCESS ){
    Z_TYPE_P(return_value)   = IS_OBJECT;
    Z_OBJVAL_P(return_value) = Z_OBJVAL_PP(obj);
    //zval_ptr_dtor(obj);
    return 0;
}
return -1;
```

The key line is :

```
Z_TYPE_P(return_value)   = IS_OBJECT;
Z_OBJVAL_P(return_value) = Z_OBJVAL_PP(obj);
```